# PyQt5 GUI Structure advice needed

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing a program for a user interface. I am quite new to Qt but I am enjoying using it, especially thanks to Qt designer. The program should go as follows: it has a main window with 2 tabs. The first tab is a login, with user/password fields and two buttons, "Login" and "Exit". "Exit" will of course exit the app, "Login" will try to send a SOAP request to a server to login. If unsuccessful, a pop-up with an error is displayed. If successful, a pop-up with a success message is shown, and the Tab2 is activated and shown, where the user can insert some data (with combobox whose values depend on some tables that the program downloads once it connects to the server). Here is a trimmed version of the code:

```
class Ui_PopupError(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(322, 101)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 221, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Wrong Username or Password. Try Again"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ok"))
class Ui_PopupSuccess(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(322, 101)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 221, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Successfully connected."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ok"))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def LoginMacro(self):
        Username = self.Usernamefield.text()
        Password = self.Passwordfield.text()
        req = urllib.request.Request("server")
        body = SOAPBody
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, body)
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
            testo = soup.get_text().strip()
            tree = ET.fromstring(testo)
            sessionid = tree.attrib['sessionid']
            self.popup = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            self.popupui = Ui_PopupSuccess()
            self.popupui.setupUi(self.popup)
            self.popup.show()
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
            self.Recap_Tab.setEnabled(True)
        except:
            self.popup = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            self.popupui = Ui_PopupError()
            self.popupui.setupUi(self.popup)
            self.popup.show()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(798, 867)
        #MainWindow created with QT Designer (long code...)
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)
        self.Login.clicked.connect(self.LoginMacro)
        #This is an example of the value which should feed the combobox:
        self.Handling_Type.addItems(REF_UDF_VALUES['udf_reference_value'][REF_UDF_VALUES['udf_cd']=='Handling Type'])
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        #Retranslate created with Qt designer....(cut)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just wanted to ask you if this is the correct way to do it. In particular, I am having problems to understand where to put the code which does the "real" things (communicate with the server). For example, I put the login code inside the MainWindow class, but I am not sure this works as I need to capture the jsessionid from this code in order to run then another code which downloads the tables. Where should I put this? If I put it in the "try" part of the code, it then tells me, when it tries to initialize the combobox in the mainwindow, that it cannot find the reference table. I know, I am a mess! :)

Thank you, and sorry for the long question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication to/from your backend should be separated from your GUI definition. I create a separate class called `API` to handle requests/responses and create an `API` instance for my `QMainWindow` to use. Here's an example where we'd like to populate a `QComboBox` with a list of users:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.api = API()

        users = self.api.get_users()
        self.user_widget = self.ui.userCombo
        self.user_widget.setModel(UserListModel(users, self))

class API:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'http://localhost:5000/api'
        self.users_url = '/users'
        self.timeout = 5

    def get_users(self):
        try:
            r = requests.get(self.base_url + self.users_url, timeout=self.timeout)
        except ConnectionError:
            print("Could not connect to API")
            return API.make_default_user_list()

        users = r.json(object_hook=API.api_hook_handler)

        return users
```

As you can see, `MainWindow` doesn't care if the request for users data succeeds or fails. Either way, `api.get_users()` returns something that the `MainWindow` can use.